# How to Display Comments to a static page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Quick question. How would I go about displaying comments to a static page from a comment box on a blog page where we are capturing name and email address and a short comment.

One page would have the comment box and the static page will have the comments.

Any help would do...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the wp_list_comments function in Wordpress

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_comments

Answer (score 0):

One typical way is to refer to a javascript that is build using database code.

When the .js file is requested, code is executed to build the javascript code so that it appears, to the browser, to have hardcoded a set of responses to show.

Then, when you post a new response, this is then added to the database, and when the javascript is refreshed, it is rebuilt, and will contain this new comment.

I don't remember the details around how to reference the script file so that the browser won't keep using the cached copy after you've added new comments, I've only used such a commenting system once, and I can't remember the name of it.

[Haloscan](http://www.haloscan.com/) is one such provider of such commenting systems.

Comment: Well in this situation I have a post page which has a form that is collecting information along with a textarea for a comment. The information is being saved to the DB just fine.

In Wordpress how would I be able to display the comment part of the information that was saved to the DB and place this information on a static page?

Comment: So on the post page I have the form and on the other page I would like to display the comments that were given off that comment form on the post page to what Wordpress calls a static page.

Thanks!